# Date object not returning the expected year

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get today's date using a JavaScript date object. When I do I run the following code:

```
var date = new Date();
date = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
```

I get this result:

```
Mon Aug 01 112 00:00:00 GMT +0200
```

Instead of today's date. I have used this exact code before with no issues. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use date.getFullYear() insted of getYear()

Comment: The mozilla documentation is usually useful for this kind of thing: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @ Naresh : Many thanks, getFullYear() works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date.getFullYear()` instead of `date.getYear()`.

> [getYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is no longer used and has been replaced by the getFullYear
>   method.
>
> The getYear method returns the year minus 1900.